# how to build dataframe by using pd.read_json with url to read a column as a string

Tags: python, json, pandas

Using the following format with `pd.read_csv` and the converter, I am able to retrieve the data from the api call and the Ticker symbols (called "code" here), I don't have the leading zeros stripped off. * api keys changed in string, will not work.

eg.

```
exchanges = ["SHE"]
for ex in exchanges:
    df = pd.read_csv(f'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/{ex}? 
       api_token=5f13457294ba20.004391&date={str(today)}',
        converters={'Code': lambda x: str(x)})
```

**results:**

code       exchange_short_name      date  ...   close          adjusted_close   volume

000001       SHE              2021-11-17  ...  18.11           18.11        66464038

000002       SHE              2021-11-17  ...  19.46           19.46        62374971

Now, When switching to `pd.read_json` method, I can no longer use the converter function I used before to convert to string. As a result, those same tickers are having the leading zeros removed.

```
exchanges = ["SHE"]
for ex in exchanges:

    df = pd.read_json(f'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/{ex}? 
       api_token=5f1323ba20.00238991&fmt=json&date={str(today)}')
```

**results:**

code    exchange_short_name   date  ...     close          adjusted_close   volume

1       SHE               2021-11-17  ...  18.11           18.11        66464038

2       SHE               2021-11-17  ...  19.46           19.46        62374971

Here is the data as seen in the actual api call via browser.

```
[{"code":"000001","exchange_short_name":"SHE","date":"2021-11-17","open":18.15,"high":18.3,"low":17.98,"close":18.11,"adjusted_close":18.11,"volume":66464038},{"code":"000002","exchange_short_name":"SHE","date":"2021-11-17","open":19.23,"high":19.53,"low":19.09,"close":19.46,"adjusted_close":19.46,"volume":62374971},
```

How can I modify that `pd.read_json` to read at least one column (code) in as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to `converters`, when adopting [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.3/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) use the `dtype` parameter passing a dict for converting values in certain columns.

```py
df = pd.read_json(f'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/...', dtype={'code':str})
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try in a few days and get back to  you.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I will mark it as accepted.